# Available check in Class

Tags: swift, swiftui

I was trying to use `PhotosPicker()` in my practice project, and use #available/@availabvle to check the IOS version. I did some research, but haven't found a way to solve this issue.

```
class PostAndCollectionVM: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var houseCollection = [RoomPostDM]()
    @Published var providerCollection = [RoomPostDM]()
    @Published var roomData: RoomPostDM = .empty
    
    if #available(iOS 16, *) {
        @Published var selectedImage: PhotosPickerItem? = nil
    } else {
        @Published var selectedImage = UIImage()
    }
}
```

Could I use `#available` directly in class without `func` or `Compute property` to wrap it, or could I need to use `@available` for the different classes like so?

```
@available(ios 16, *) class collectionVM {}

@available(ios, obsoleted: 15, *) clas class collectionVM2 {}
```

Comment: You can't use availability to determine whether to make a property declaration. There are no ifs about property declarations, they are not executable code.

Comment: Thank you for replying, so I gotta duplicate the class for a different version right? or do you have a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: Duplicate the class? You can't have two classes with the same name either.

Comment: Oh, I mean with a different name for these two classes but thank you for helping. really appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

This can be done, but with the following restrictions/changes:

1. You cannot use the same variable name
2. You will need to setup the variable within an availability `if`
   statement

   ```
   class Test: ObservableObject {

   @available(iOS 13, *)
   @Published var x: String? = nil

   @available(iOS 14, *)
   @Published var y: String? = nil

   init()
   {
       if #available(iOS 14, *)
       {
           self.y = "iOS 14"
       }
       else
       {
           // 'y' is only available in application extensions for iOS 14 or newer
           self.y = "iOS 13"
       }
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: Variables with storage cannot be declared with an `@available` attribute that is lower than the deployment target so the code will not compile when the deployment target is lower than iOS 14.

Comment: @Allan I am using this in my project that has a minimum deployment target of iOS 12. It compiles and works correctly.

Comment: Are you using the Swift 5.6 compiler? It has a bug that accepts this code. It is no longer allowed in Swift 5.7. If the property with `@available` were of a type that is not actually available when back deployed then the app would crash when back deployed regardless of the available annotation.

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-14-release-notes where it refers to 82713248